What is loadlin.exe in Debian installation image(.iso) explained for a newbie?
So I opened the Debian .iso image and in a directory "tools" there were loadlin.exe and loadlin.txt. I tried researching but everything was from 2005-ish. What does it do? What happens if I run it? Where is it applicable? (I'm right now running windows 10 by the way)

my recollection is that its used in the case that you insert a Debian live-cd when you are already booted into windows, and gave you options like rebooting into the live CD, or even beginning an install while still in windows (though nothing is really installed until the system is rebooted. thats what I recall, but its going quite a ways back in time.
